# (C++) Finding all prime numbers between two integers (without using sieve of Eratosthanes)

Tags: c++, primes

I'm trying to find all the prime numbers between two integers and place them in an integer array.

The catch is that i have to use a specific method of doing so (divide each subsequent integer by all the primes in my array). So I can't use the sieve of Eratosthanes or any other 'easier' methods.

My code successfully prompts the user for two integers, but for now I do not use either of them. First I want to make sure the program works for values between 0 and whatever, in this case 200 just to test it.

Problem is, when I run the program and print the first 20 or so values in the array, I'm getting

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...... more zeroes.

The first 5 values are correct because they start in the array, but after that the whole thing goes haywire.

I've worked through my nested loop by hand for a couple values and it SEEMS like it should work. I feel like there's a specific array property that I'm overlooking.

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "climits"
#include "cmath"
#include "array"
using namespace std;


int main()
{

// declare variables to store user input
int lowerBound, upperBound;

// prompt user for lesser and greater integers and store them
cout << "Program to find all primes between two integers." << endl;
cout << "Enter lesser integer: " << endl;
cin >> lowerBound;
cout << "Enter greater integer: " << endl;
cin >> upperBound;

// if statement to switch the input variables if the user accidentally enters them backwards
if (lowerBound > upperBound) {
    int temp = lowerBound;
    lowerBound = upperBound;
    upperBound = temp;
}

// initialize int array with the first 5 primes
int primes[100] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };

// loop to find primes between 12 and 200 (since we already have primes from 1-11 in the array)
for (int i = 12; i <= 200; i++) {

    // the maximum divisor needed to determine if the current integer being tested is prime
    double maxDivisor = sqrt(i);

    // variable for the current size of the array
    int size = 5;

    // boolean variable is set to true by default
    bool isPrime = true;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {     // changed "j<=size" to "j<size"
        int remainder = (i % primes[j]);

        // once the maximum divisor is reached, there is no need to continue testing for the current integer
        if (primes[j] > maxDivisor) {
            break;
        }

        // if the remainder of divison by a prime is 0, the number is not prime, so set the boolean variable to false
        if (remainder = 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }

    // if isPrime is still true after the nested loop, the integer value being tested will be placed in the next element of the array
    if (isPrime == true) {
        primes[size] = i;

        // since we added to the array, increment size by 1
        size++;
    }

}

// display the first 20 values in the array for debugging
for (int k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    cout << primes[k] << ", ";
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++) {` this will iterate from [0,5] inclusive! This is probably not what you wan't right? it should probably be `j < size`. Might not be the only thing.

Comment: You set `size` to 5 inside the `for` loop. So for every prime you check, it will always be 5.

Comment: This was my problem haha. Can't believe I missed that. After moving the "size" declaration out of the for loop, the program properly finds all the primes between 0 and 200. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This here

```
if (remainder = 0) {
    isPrime = false;
}
```

Needs to be changed to

```
if (remainder == 0) {
    isPrime = false;
}
```

Because `=` does assignment, not comparison. So what `remainder = 0` does it setting `remainder` to `0`, and then it returns that `0`, which gets casted to `false`, which is on of the reasons why it's not finding any primes.

Also, as Fantastic Mr Fox pointed out, `for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++)` needs to be changed to `for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)`.

Also, did your compiler issue any warnings? If not, try to see if you can set it to be more strict with warnings. I figure most modern compilers will give you a hint at `if (remainder = 0)`. Getting useful warnings from the compiler helps a lot with preventing bugs.

Edit:
As Karsten Koop pointed out, you need to move the `int size = 5;` out of the loop, to before the `for (int i = 12;`. With those changes, it's now working on my machine.

Last but not least, a tip: instead of `if (isPrime == true)`, you can just write `if (isPrime)`.

Comment: Ok, so i changed the "=" to "==" and "<=" to "<". Now, my output reads 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 199, 0, 0, 0... the only change being that 200 is now 199. Strange.

Comment: You also need to regard Karsten Koop's comment about moving the `int size = 5;`. Then it should work, at least it does for me.